# Using ACL on related objects

Tags: angularjs, parse-platform, acl

My app is an angularjs/ionic/parse.com/phonegap one and i am looking for ways to achieve the following.

I have a category within which are articles.
Some categories are open to all users, others are password protected. 
Once the user enters the password, they have access to articles within the protected category.
I plan to implement parse.com ACL's but not sure where this should be applied, on the category or the articles. If i apply them to the category and relate articles as arrays, does Parse auto matically implement the ACL to all child articles to which the array points to?

Comment: No, Parse doesn't automatically apply ACLs to the child objects. Here, you need to explicitly set ACLs of the articles. I guess your private category has some public info (like its name, etc.), so you can keep its ACL as open to all users. But you keep the ACLs of its child articles as private.

Comment: Thought as much. Add it as an answer and i can vote it.